# How to set selected tab job in on create

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

I have 3 tabs containing difference `Fragments` as:

1. Product and Services
2. Business Directory
3. Job

Bellow is my TabFragement Adapter The code is worked correctly but only 1 thing I want is:
=> I want to set Job `Fragment` as default in `onCreate`

[image]

This is my `adapter`.

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {
    public static TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int int_items = 3 ;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout,null);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });

        return x;

    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch (position){
                case 0 : return new Product_Service();
                case 1 : return new Business_Dir();
                case 2 : return new Job();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return int_items;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return "Product & Srevices";
                case 1 :
                    return "Business Directory";
                case 2 :
                    return "Job";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to show the 3rd fragment on the top

Comment: use setCurrentTab(3) to show selected fragment Job

Comment: yes when I start the activity it display 3rd selected

Answer (score 3):

You can use the fragment position index to show particular fragment as default using `setCurrentItem` method of`ViewPager` [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem%28int,%20boolean%29). Do this after setting `adapter` on `viewpager`

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(2, false); // job fragment index is 2
```

`false` here mean , the transition to `fragment` 3 will be done instantly and if you pass `true` then chosen `fragment` will be displayed using scrolling effects ( you can use `true` when you want to give a little tour to user for first time)

Comment: Thanks Pavneet Singh, Your answer are work, but when I try to use it in main activity it geting error, HERE IS MY CODE `mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();TabFragment.viewPager.setCurrentItem(2, false); // job fragment index is 2`

Comment: you can update your question with code of `mainactivity`  plus add the logcat error too

Comment: seems like error is `TabFragment.viewPager.setCurrentItem‌​(2, false)`  you are doing this too early i.e. your fragment and tab is not ready to use ,so put this line after this `tabLayout.setupWithViewPage`